# The deleted index of array reappears in the awk after using it in the expression

Tags: awk

I found strange behavior in the `awk`. I wanted to delete an array element, but found, that this element (just an index, without a value) appears again, if I used it somewhere in the code after the deletion. Is this expected behavior?

```
awk '
# This function just for clarity and convenience.
function check(item) {
    if(item in arr) 
        printf "the array index \"%s\" exists\n\n", item 
    else 
        printf "the array index \"%s\" does not exist\n\n", item 
}

END {
    # Create element of array with index "f"
    arr["f"] = "yes"

    printf "The value of arr[\"f\"] before deleting = \"%s\"\n", arr["f"]

    # The first checking of the array - the index exists
    check("f")

    # Then delete this element
    # I am expecting no this element in the "arr" now
    delete arr["f"]

    # The second checking of the array - the index does not exist
    # as I were expecting
    check("f")

    # Use the non-existent index in expression
    printf "The value of arr[\"f\"] after deleting = \"%s\"\n", arr["f"]

    # The third checking of the array - the index exists again
    check("f")
}' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
The value of arr["f"] before deleting = "yes"
the array index "f" exists

the array index "f" does not exist

The value of arr["f"] after deleting = ""
the array index "f" exists
```

Comment: This is expected.  Referencing the value of an variable will create it if it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  Referencing the value of a variable will create it if it does not yet exist.  Otherwise, the following would be a syntax error:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "Foo is " foo[0]; foo[0]="bar"; print "Foo is " foo[0]; delete foo[0]; print "Foo is " foo[0] }'
Foo is
Foo is bar
Foo is
```

This is true even for non-arrayed variables, but since there is no `delete` operator (sometimes) for flat variables, this doesn't come up often without arrays being involved in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you encounter is because this line recreates silently the array item you deleted before:

```
printf "The value of arr[\"f\"] after deleting = \"%s\"\n", arr["f"]
```

See this small test:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a[1];delete a[1];for (i in a) print i}'
# nothing is printed
$ awk 'BEGIN{a[1];delete a[1];a[1];for (i in a) print i}'
1
$ awk 'BEGIN{a[1];delete a[1];print "a[1]=",a[1];for (i in a) print "key found:",i}'
a[1]= 
key found: 1
```

Comment: I think it's rather important to note that not just will `a[1]` return a valid value (the empty string, similar to referencing any unassigned variable), but also that _the referenced key then shows up when listing the keys_ with the `for (i in a)` loop. And none of this has anything to do with `delete` per se, it works as well without it, e.g. `awk 'BEGIN { x=a["abc"]; for (k in a) print k; }'` prints `abc`.